# @HostBinding('disabled') not working with Angular material 12

Tags: angular, angular-material

A custom directive ...

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]',
})
export class MyDirective {

  @HostBinding('disabled')
  disabled = true;

  constructor() { }

  @Input('myDirective')
  set myData(data: string[]) {
    this.disabled = someDirectiveLogic(data);
  }
  
  // ...
}
```

... has some specific logic to disable a button. When using the directive on a plain HTML button:

```
<a mat-raised-button color="accent"
  [disabled]="system.selection.length === 0"
>View</a>

<button color="accent"
  [myDirective]="system.selection"
>Pause</button>
```

The directive works well:

- No selection, disables the button on the right:
  [image: Standard button, no selection and disabled state]
- Selecting data, enables the button the right:
  [image: Standard button, selection and enabled state]

When adding the mat-raised-button property on the Pause button with Angular Material v12, the button always shows as enabled: [image: Material button, no selection and should be disabled]

The same code works well with Angular Material v6.3, the disabled attribute set by directive will render well in combination with mat-raised-button.

Cannot we use @HostBinding('disabled') with Angular material 12 ?

Comment: could you try `@HostBinding('attr.disabled')`

Comment: Hi @Andrei, using `@HostBinding('attr.disabled')` does not change the behavior of the button with `mat-raised-button`. Also this change breaks the enabling/disabling of the standard button (without `mat-raised-button`) by the custom directive :(

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the source code for the Angular Material button, I found a solution which works with a standard button, and a material button.

As in line 70 of [button.ts](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button/button.ts), I noticed that using the `host` property metadata instead of the `HostBinding` decorator, works as expected. So the directive is now implemented as:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]',
  host: {
    '[attr.disabled]': 'disabled || null',
    '[class.mat-button-disabled]': 'disabled',
  },
})
export class MyDirective {

  disabled = true;

  constructor() { }

  @Input('myDirective')
  set myData(data: string[]) {
    this.disabled = someDirectiveLogic(data);
  }
  
  // ...
}
```

This example is illustrated in [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3eh8uj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-directive.directive.ts) .

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify [the answer by adelinor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70146267),

The `disabled` property of a `<button>` is a [Boolean attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes), the presence of which indicates the `true` value, and the absence of which indicates the `false` value.

[Testing out how Boolean values bound by Angular are reflected in HTML](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ravinduwu-misc-angular-boolean-html-attributes?file=src%2Fapp.component.html), notice that `[attr.disabled]="true"` and `[attr.disabled]="false"` result in `<button disabled="true">` and `<button disabled="false">` respectively. The `disabled` attribute is present on both and therefore they are disabled.

Angular's [attribute binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#syntax) removes the attribute altogether if the bound value is `null` or `undefined`, which is why the expression `disabled || null` works.